# Can I Adjust the Camera?

Tags: akaneiro-demon-hunters

Unlike most Torchlight/Diablo type games, the mouse scroll wheel in *Akaneiro: Demon Hunters* doesn't appear to move my camera in or out (zoom).  Is there any way I can adjust my field of view?